# Mongodb timestamp is very inaccurate - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to store objects in mongodb, I record the createdAt date by using Date.now()

What I am finding is that the wrong time is being stored in the database. The difference is very sporadic and has been 7 days, 3 days and even 5 minutes off.

Just this morning I created an object at 8.00AM (GMT+10) AEST, yet the time in the database was 7 days earlier.

This is the database object:

```
{
  "_id": "554bdfaf797cb8e02753e06f",
  "description": "test d",
  "createdBy": "testuser",
  "key": "f1a593f4dd51e632388a1755e09a7b4dc0bc0e24ef8bcf5cf859ac759a45e8a6",
  "__v": 0,
  "files": [],
  "createdAt": "2015-05-01T05:42:07.687Z"
}
```

I have seen this issue on both on my mac and win 7.

First noticed on mongodb version 2.6.3, just upgraded to 3.0.2, no change.

**Update**

I am setting the createdAt date within the schema like so:

```
var uploadSchema = new Schema({
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now()
     },
```

My database and application are running on the same host.

gist here - https://gist.github.com/reecefenwick/1bcff85d18406b33e5cf

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What's going on is that you're *calling* `Date.now()` at the time the schema is defined to set the default value for `createdAt`, and then that value is being used for the default until the next time your app is restarted.

Instead, you want to set the default value to the `Date.now` function itself so that it will be called each time a new doc is created:

```
var uploadSchema = new Schema({
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
     },
```

Comment: Wow.... thank you. I have also moved to using pre.('save') middleware so you can't overwrite it with any date you want.

Comment: Thank you buddy, you've just saved me and my teammates lives

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the object id into the website here:

http://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/

You will see that this specific document was created today (`2015-05-07T21:57:03.000Z`). The object id contains creation date information.

Where's the code for where you are creating the `createdAt` entry? Is the database and your application code on separate servers? This could explain why mongo is creating the object id with a different date than `createdAt`.

If they are on the same server, you should post the code that is creating the `createAt` time string.

Comment: That page is really helpful, didn't realise the timestamp was embedded in the ObjectID!

I added a link to a gist containing my code. Still haven't resolved it yet :(